# Unit-testing iPhone rotation

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode

My iPhone application has several views and some viewControllers for that views.

I need to test how viewControllers react to device rotations (switch between Portrait and Landscape device orientations).

I found some info about OCMock and google-toolbox-for-mac frameworks but not found any answers on this topic.

Some views may have Landscape/Portrait feature enabled and some not.
I need to test the state of view after number of random (or predefined) device' rotations.

I don't have any ideas about how to do that without real user actions.

Will may anybody help me in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: I have found the solution in other related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15642432/2777364).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few possible solutions:

- [This one](http://code.google.com/p/accelerometer-simulator/) allows you to connect your iPhone/Touch and send accelerometer events to the simulator.
- If you prefer to use your Mac laptop as the accelerometer source [here's another way](http://ifiddling.blogspot.com/2009/01/dummy2.html) to do it.
- Similar in concept but [slightly different implementation](http://www.iphonearch.com/topic/6/iphone-accelerometer-simulator/).

In all cases you can take the output coming out from these apps and save them to a data file  then read them back during testing to simulate user motion.

Comment: The 3-rd way allow to simulate acclerometer events without hardware accelerometer. I think it more flexible. I will try it today. Thank you, Ramin!

Comment: 3rd link doesn't work. Can you describe what was the solution? Also avoid giving link-only answers, because they can invalided over time.