# How do I rotate the iOS simulator using code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, applescript

Does anyone know how to rotate the iOS Simulator (6.0 and above)?  I've searched but have found nothing on this.

I am trying to do this through code (not manually), but if it can be done through a script, then it has to be run from code. Can this even be done? Some advice needed.

Comment: Since there is a ShortChut (Cmd+arrow), you can't use this?

Comment: The purpose is for running over 2k tests, so i'd prefer a code solution. But i just cant seem to find anything on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an entry for Supported interface orientations to the Tests target (or whatever target is appropriate) like this:

[image: Target Settings]

As long as the only entries are Landscape ones, it will run in Landscape mode.

*Edit:*
If I misunderstood your comment about tests and you aren't running unit tests, you probably don't want to keep changing the orientation of your main target. In that case, you could duplicate your main target and make the orientation change there.

*Edit:*
There is an undocumented method to force rotation in code. While this will work for tests, it could get your app rejected if you use it in a submitted app.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];
```

Just include this category wherever you need to use this method.

```
@interface UIDevice (MethodsThatAppleWillHitMeWithTheBanStickForUsing)
    -(void)setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation animated:(BOOL)animated;
    -(void)setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;
@end
```

Comment: But then how do i change the simulator orientation through code? i'm looking for something like -> setSimulatorOrientationRight (and then the simulator would turn right or left etc..)  I just need something to act the same way as pressing command+arrowButton. The tests are not XCode unit tests; they are custom ones.

Comment: See my edit. Like I said, this will most likely get your app rejected if you use it in production code, but for your tests it should be good enough.

Comment: Just what i needed man. Thanks. keep in mind, not every app thats built is intended to go to the app store. With the thousands of app out there, there are testing environments built to accommodate apps that will **eventually** get to the app store. This app is for such an environment. It will never be in the store. Thanks for the precaution :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are couple of steps you have to check to make all orientations work in iOS6. Even if one of them is missing it won't work.

1. As Lance says, yes you have to set the supported orientations for iphone or ipad whatever appropriate.
2. Write this code in the controller which you want to set the rotation for.

   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
       return *UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;*
   }

   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
   {
       return YES;
   }

Change *UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll* depending on what orientations you want.

1. If you are using a navigation controller in your project make sure you set it properly!

You shouldn't be getting this error...(Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch)

Get these steps right and rotation will work for you.

Comment: Sry,i get what youre saying. However my sort of tests are different entirely. I dont even have access to the code im will be testing :) . Lance got it tho, i just needed to rotate the simulator through code. His solution works.