# How to rotate simulator using Swift code in xcode ui test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have a scenario where I have to rotate my simulator while xcode ui test is going.

To rotate the simulator, I use the below code

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

but it is not working.

Is there any solution to rotate the simulator using Swift code in xcode ui test?

Comment: TRY THIS [How To Rotate Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642135/how-do-i-rotate-the-ios-simulator-using-code)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried this?

### Swift 2.x

```
XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().orientation = .LandscapeLeft  
XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().orientation = .Portrait
```

### Swift 3.0

```
XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .landscapeLeft
XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .portrait
```

### Swift 5.x

```
XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .landscapeLeft
XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .portrait
```

Comment: Np glad to help @user6633897

Comment: **@Rashwan** if i want to print the state of Simulator in console?.

Comment: Means if i rotate my simulator to portrait mode, it will print portrait as well as lndscape

Comment: Try `print(XCUIDevice.shared().orientation)`@iDeveloper

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4:

```
XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .landscapeLeft
XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .portrait
```

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat it is the simulated device, you need to import XCTest