# Getting the error "Cannot find 'XCUIDevice' in scope" for a Swift UI test

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to call `XCUID.sharedDevice().orientation = .Portrait` in my Swift UI test and getting the error `Cannot find 'XCUIDevice' in scope`.

Here is my file:

```
import XCTest

final class FastlaneScreenshotsLaunchTests: XCTestCase {
    override class var runsForEachTargetApplicationUIConfiguration: Bool {
        true
    }

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }
            
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        setupSnapshot(app)
        app.launch()
    }

    func testLaunch() throws {
        snapshot("0Launch")
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().orientation = .Portrait // Cannot find 'XCUIDevice' in scope
    }

}
```

Based on google searching what I'm trying to do (rotate the simulator), I'm expecting XCUIDevice to be in scope.
Here are places which recommend this code:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/12437
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39703082/3569329

**EDIT:
The issue was one of my destinations for my test target was Mac Catalyst, which does not support XCUIDevice. Once I removed the mac catalyst destination, the error was resolved.**

Thanks to @vadim-belyaev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern syntax is:

```swift
XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .portrait
```

Comment: The problem is that `XCUIDevice` itself is not in scope, so the above also results in an error for me.

Comment: If you don't use XCUIDevice, do your UI tests run successfully? If yes, which version of Xcode are you using? Also, is this an iOS app?

Comment: Thanks @vadim-belyaev, the issue was I had mac catalyst as one of the destinations. Once I removed that, the issue was resolved.